# Simple C#: How to check String input is both a valid number AND less than a certain number?

Tags: c#

I know the && int.TryParse(birthMonth, out monthInt) == false) is where my issue is, but I posted it to better explain my question.

I am looking to verify the user input (String) to be a number and less than or equal to 12 -- a valid month.

```
 // Get user's month of birth
        Console.Write("\nFascinating! What month? (1-12): ");
        birthMonth = Console.ReadLine();

        // Check to see if user input for month is a number
        int monthInt;
        while (int.Parse(birthMonth) >= 13 && int.TryParse(birthMonth, out monthInt) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter a number less than, or equal to 12!");
            birthMonth = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: You don't need to use `int.Parse` and `int.TryParse` together like that. Just use `int.TryParse` in this scenario. Read up on how the `out` works here and you can drop the `int.Parse(birthMonth)` completely

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input should

- represent `int`, i.e. `int.TryParse` should return `true`
- be at least `1`
- be at most `12`

`While` any of these conditions *fail* (`!` - inversion), loop:

```
while (!(int.TryParse(birthMonth, out monthInt) && monthInt >= 1 && monthInt <= 12)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse first using `int.TryParse` and then check the parsed number like:

```
while (!int.TryParse(birthMonth, out monthInt) || monthInt >=13)
```

Also you have to check if the `monthInt` is less than `1`.

Couple of things to note:

- Use `int.TryParse` since it will not throw exception in case of failure.
- use `||` since this will do short circuit evaluation and correct operator for your conditions.

Comment: Also, in case you're offended by the magic number, you could use a `TotalCalendarYearMonths` constant.

Comment: Or get the actual number of months ;) `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetMonthsInYear(DateTime.Today.Year)`

Comment: You have to add `monthInt <= 0` condition in case of `-123` or `0` input

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, I have added a note for it just below the code. I wanted to op to know what he is doing wrong in his code and understands short circuit evaluation.

Comment: @Habib, any reason you didn't use while (int.TryParse(birthMonth, out monthInt) && monthInt <=12)

Comment: @PaulTsai, look at the message, `Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter a number less than, or equal to 12!");` I guess op wanted the user to input a valid number until the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `Parse` and `TryParse`, parsing the value twice, when one time is enough:

```
int parsedMonth;

if (int.TryParse(birthMonth, out parsedMonth))
{
    if (parsedMonth < 13)
    {
        // do whatever you need with the value
    }
    else
    {
        // out of range
    }
}
else
{
    // not a number
}
```

`TryParse` returns `true` or `false` after parsing the value; `Parse` would throw an exception in case of invalid input.

This is not the most compact way of writing it out but you can follow the logic more easily with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TryParse` to attempt to parse a string value to a primitive. All of the primitives - `bool`, `int`, `byte`, `DateTime`, etc. - have this method. Make a function to validate the input:

```
var birthMonth = Console.ReadLine();
int month;

if(!ValidateMonth(birthMonth, out month) {
    // process invalid month or whatever
}

bool ValidateBirthMonth(string birthMonth, out int month) {
    var month = default(int);

    if(!int.TryParse(birthMonth, out month)) {
        Console.WriteLine("invalid month");

        return;
    }

    if (month >= 1 && month <= 12) {
        Console.WriteLine("... great!!!");

        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("invalid entry: month must be 1-12");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just check using TryParse and and conditions together as below.

```
int outvar = -1;
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out outvar) && (outvar<=0 && outvar>12))
            {
                //your rest of the code
            }
```